# Draw string on picturebox image

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I draw a `string` by `GraphicsPath` on a `PictureBox` and I let users move the string on picturebox by mouse dragging. Now I want to save the image so that the string falls just on the place where he dragged it on the picturebox. I tried this:

```
float dx, dy;
private void closeWindow()
{
    MessageBox.Show(NinjaClass.NINJA.location.ToString());
    NinjaClass.NINJA.location = strPoint;//new Point(strPoint.X, strPoint.Y);

    NinjaClass.NINJA.imgOpened = pictureBox1.Image;

    Image tmp = Image.FromFile(NinjaClass.NINJA.ImgOrignalPath);
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(tmp);
    gr.DrawString(NinjaClass.NINJA.copyrightStr, NinjaClass.NINJA.font, new SolidBrush(NinjaClass.NINJA.color), new PointF(dx, dy));
    NinjaClass.NINJA.imgOpened = tmp;
    NinjaClass.NINJA.saveOpenedFile();


    this.Close();
    this.Dispose();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    gp.Transform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, dx, dy));//Translate and paint
    e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(color), gp);
    gp.Transform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -dx, -dy));//translate back (reset to old location)
}

//MouseDown event handler for your pictureBox1
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        strPoint = e.Location;
        if (gp.GetBounds(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, dx, dy)).Contains(e.Location))
        {
            gp.Transform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, dx, dy));
        }
    }
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        pboxPoint = e.Location;
    }
}
//MouseMove event handler for your pictureBox1
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        dx = e.X - strPoint.X;
        dy = e.Y - strPoint.Y;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        NinjaClass.NINJA.location = new PointF(strPoint.X, strPoint.Y);
    }
    else if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        pictureBox1.Left += e.X - (int)pboxPoint.X;
        pictureBox1.Top += e.Y - (int)pboxPoint.Y;
        //NinjaClass.NINJA.location = pictureBox1.Location;
    }

}

private void ScaleWindow_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape))
    {
        this.closeWindow();
    }
}
```

But I'm facing some position problem. I mean the string of saved image gets different position than the position where user dragged it on the picturebox.

**Update:** Here is the function that saves the image:

```
public void saveOpenedFile()
{
    imgOpened.Save(imgSavePath);
    MessageBox.Show("Saved as ' " + imgSavePath + " '");
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What is the SizeMode of the picture box? That may take part in this!

Comment: Is `saveOpenedFile()` doing it?  Where's that code?  And where do the values for this come from:  `new PointF(dx, dy)`?

Comment: Please see the updates. `pictureBox1` is currently on `CenterImage` SizeMode. Apologies for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

In method `closeWindow`, I wonder why you set value of `NinjaClass.NINJA.imgOpened` twice. I think you have to make change against image in **pictureBox1** instead of the original image which you loaded to **tmp** object.

Could you try this code?

```
float dx, dy;
private void closeWindow()
{
    MessageBox.Show(NinjaClass.NINJA.location.ToString());
    NinjaClass.NINJA.location = strPoint;//new Point(strPoint.X, strPoint.Y);

    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    gr.DrawString(NinjaClass.NINJA.copyrightStr, NinjaClass.NINJA.font, new SolidBrush(NinjaClass.NINJA.color), new PointF(dx, dy));
    NinjaClass.NINJA.imgOpened = pictureBox1.Image;
    NinjaClass.NINJA.saveOpenedFile();


    this.Close();
    this.Dispose();
}
```